# pick id of the user who is not logged in

Tags: django, django-views

In this my views I get users by their exact name example www.mysite.com/usuario1
and so far it's working, but I need it in the photos section to get only the photos of that user1
and that user1 is not logged into the system.
how do I pull only the photos of the user1?

models.py

```
    class Photo(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        file = StdImageField( upload_to='photos/', blank=False,  variations={
            'large': (600, 400),
            'thumbnail': (100, 100, True),
            'medium': (300, 200),
        })
        uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Negocio(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
    def profile_detail(request, username):
        if User.objects.get(username__iexact=username):
            user_details = User.objects.get(username__iexact=username)
            photos_list =  Photo.objects.filter(user=request.username.pk)
            return render(request, "profile.html", {
                "user_details": user_details, 'photos': photos_list
            })
        else:
            return render("User not found")
```

profile.html

```
        {% for photo in photos %}

          <img src="{{ photo.file.medium.url}}"class="img-thumbnail" width="200" height="200"> 

              {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a queryset for the photos, you can access them through the `User` instance using the [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), if you don't set a related_name you can just append [_set](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) to the model name like this:

```
photos_list =  user_details.photo_set.all()
```

But you don't really need the queryset at all in your view, in your template you can do this:

```
{% for photo in user_details.photo_set.all %}
    <img src="{{ photo.file.medium.url}}"class="img-thumbnail" width="200" height="200"> 
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you get the user, but then you don't pass it to your Photo filter - instead you pass the logged-in user there. Just use the user you got:

```
photos_list =  Photo.objects.filter(user=user_details)
```

Note, your first line will fail if the user does not exist, because the query will raise a DoesNotExist exception. A better way to do it would be:

```
def profile_detail(request, username):
    user_details = get_object_or_40o4(User, username__iexact=username)
    photos_list =  Photo.objects.filter(user=user_details)
    return render(request, "profile.html", {
        "user_details": user_details, 'photos': photos_list
    })
```

which will automatically show a 404 (not found) page if the username does not exist.